# React Router v4 params breaking inside unit test when mounting

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I have a React component that has URL params. When I run the test and mount the component the params are always undefined and as a result, break the test. I have tried to hard code them as constants, props and it still won't work. Any other ideas I can try?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BarcodePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { SKU, ID } = this.props.match.params
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Barcode view {SKU} {ID}</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default BarcodePage;


import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import BarcodePage from './BarcodePage';

const component = mount(
  <BarcodePage params={{SKU: '1111', ID: '2121212' }} />
);

describe('<BarcodePage />', () => {
  it('render one header', () => {
    expect(component.find('h1').length).toBe(1);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React Router provides and your code uses `this.props.match.params`, not `this.props.params`. You're passing the wrong props to your unit test:

```
<BarcodePage params={{SKU: '1111', ID: '2121212' }} />
```

That gives you `this.props.params`, but it should be `this.props.match.params`:

```
<BarcodePage match={{params: {SKU: '1111', ID: '2121212' }}} />
```

Comment: thanks so much. smallest little thing was giving me a headache.